# JavaScript Slide Show in a Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have an assignment to create s pseudo "slide show" on a webpage using javascript. The idea is to have one image displayed on the screen with buttons below it that the user can click to select which image they wish to see. I'm trying to do this by altering the "display" property value in a short javascript, but the buttons aren't doing anything.

JavaScript:

```
function Apples()
        {
            document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
        }
        function Grapes()
        {
            document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
        }
        function Strawberries()
        {
            document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="inline";
        }
```

Html Buttons:

```
<input type="submit" value="Apples" onClick="Apples()" />
<input type="submit" value="Grapes" onClick="Grapes()" />
<input type="submit" value="Strawberries" onClick="Strawberries()" />
```

"Apples" "Grapes" and "Strawberries" used in the javascript are the id's that I gave to each of the images.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";` etc...

Comment: now the Strawberry button works, but the others don't. Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having some naming conflicts. Values on Inputs, ID's and Names etc

this is working http://jsfiddle.net/3TbMC/

I have changed your method names to `showApples` and `showGrapes` etc...

JS

```
function showApples()
{
    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
};

function showGrapes()
{
    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
};

function showStrawberries()
{
    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="inline";
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Apples" onClick="showApples();" />
<input type="submit" value="Grapes" onClick="showGrapes();" />
<input type="submit" value="Strawberries" onClick="showStrawberries();" />
```

Comment: ah. yep now it works. my names must have been causing conflicts as you suggested! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/latoc/2/edit)**

Why not simply change the `background-image` of a `DIV` like:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var n = btn.length;
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var images = {
  "Apples"    : "apples.jpg", // Property MUST MATCH the button value
  "Grapes"    : "grapes.jpg",
  "Strawberry": "strawz.jpg"
};

function changeImage(){
  console.log(images[this.value]);
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ images[this.value] +')';
}

for(var i=0;i<n;i++) btn[i].onclick = changeImage;
```

```
<div id="image"></div>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Apples" />
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Grapes" />
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Strawberry" />
```

```
#image{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(apples.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: this is a course assignment. in class we discussed three different ways to display different images (changing z-index, changing visibility, and changing display). We had to select one of these three ways to do the assignment and then explain why we chose the one that we did. This is a good suggestion though and I will keep this in mind for the future.